# UNIX Command for Java program, input text from another directory

Tags: macos, io-redirection

I will normally run my Java Program with input file in my current directory.

```
java myClass < input.txt > output.txt
```

However, what should I type if my input file is in another directory (eg. thumbdrive), and I want to save my output file to that same external directory too?

Comment: What have you tried? Does giving it the absolute path or relative path fail?

Comment: I don't really know how to write an absolute path, but I got it figured out. Thanks alot for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried specifying the full path, e.g.

```
java myClass < /media/thumbdrive/input.txt > /media/thumbdrive/output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I don't really know how to write an absolute path. But then I remembered you can drag and drop stuff into Mac's Terminal.

So to read/write to another directory, just provide the absolute path.

```
java TestShell < /Users/me/Downloads/intput.txt  > /Users/me/Downloads/output.txt
```

Comment: `/Users/me` and so on is osx specific. Why did you tag your question as UNIX?